# mysql error while creating two tables

Tags: mysql

```
mysql >create table  customer (cust_id int PRIMARY KEY, cust_name  varchar(20));

Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.82 sec)

mysql> create table  order (cust_id int, order_id int);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (cust_id int, order_id int)' at line 1
```

These are my two table but I am getting this error

Comment: `order` is a keyword in sql

Comment: if you want to create table with order name you write in quote. Like that 'order'

Answer (score 2):

Order is a keyword. So use ` character like below.

```
create table  `order` (cust_id int, order_id int);
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for getting this error is because you've used a keyword as table name "*order*" directly in the `CREATE` statement.

To fix this, you can either change the table name from "*order*" to "*orders*" or use the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE `order` (cust_id int, order_id int);
```

Using the above query will create table with name "*order*" in db. Only thing to note here is that you will always have to use quotes to access this table.

E.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM `order';
```

Answer (score 1):

`order` is a key word of mysql
so use below

```
create table  orders (cust_id int, order_id int);
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is due to the table name.You are using "order" as table but order is a keyword in mysql.Try giving it some other name